# Angularjs access res.render variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

I am passing variable data from res.render like this

```
res.render('employment/employment', { title: 'Sheet | Employee',username:    
req.session.name,DateTime:result-date,time-sheet:time-sheet});
```

The above is first render. And in my angularjs have a route like this

```
$routeProvider
.when('/employeeTimeSheet',{
controller:'MainCtrl',
templateUrl:'/partials/employeeTimeSheet.html'
})
.when('/employeeLogin',{
controller:'MainCtrl',
templateUrl:'/employeeDashboard'
})
.otherwise({redirectTo:'/employeeLogin'});

});
```

So it redirects to employeeLogin. Here I have a partial and the route for this is like this on expressjs

```
app.get('/employeeDashboard', function(req, res){
res.render('employelogin/employeeDashboard');
});
```

Here the problem is the partial keeps on loading..many times and I need to pass data from one render to another render.

Comment: I don't get you. Why angularjs need to access variable in server side render? angularjs only work it magic in client side javascript. you don't put your ng-scope binding in jade and angular will bind your data in client side.

Comment: I tried getting it on jade template...when the jade template is loaded in ng-view the jade variables are not processed. Which is why i thought to go angular way.

Comment: There is some date coming from DB nad I have to redirect it after that, so I have to pass the variables in res.render right..

Comment: If I understand corretly the dates are not display in human readable string, so you need to process the dates to human readable string before passing it to jade, using like moment.js.

Comment: I tried adding a jade variable in my partial and loaded it to ng-view its same...I dont see the jade being processed.

Comment: how do you request the partials, you put your partial in public folder? that will not render by jade. you need to go through your server route.

Comment: Yes, its in the public folder of the project. In that cases where am I supposed to put it?

Comment: in the views, then write a route for each of your partials, all partials must go through the res.render().

Comment: I tried that..but the view keeps on loading...say it loads..then again loads..goes on..

Comment: update your question, show your route, render, and angular $routeProvider.when()